# R plot() - why do my points appear as horizontal lines

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a plot in R. My x-axis is a week number converted to factor and my y-axis is an amount.
When I run `plot()` instead of dots I get horizontal lines.
Why does this happen?
Here is a sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(fin_week=as.factor(seq(1,20, by =1)), amount=(rnorm(20)^2)*100)
plot(df)
```

Comment: When given a factor on the `x` axis, `plot` will use boxplots by default. Since you only have one observation per x value, the boxplot is reduced to a line.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation, it's because the first column is a factor. When R tries to find the right plot() to run, it looks into plot.dataframe, where it plots on the type of 1st column i.e a factor. Hence it plots using plot.factor(), which gives a line by default, which is used for box plots.

try using plot.default(df) to plot and you should get it the scatter plot